# Source for Dragonology rules?

Tags: untagged

Recently acquired a copy of Dragonology via an Estate Sale, and there were no rules.  Based on the [article](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/24067/dragonology-game) at board game geek, it looks like we have everything we need, except the rules.

I followed several links in internet searches, but they seemed to lead to phishing sites.  I couldn't find any legitimate (or non-evil) looking download for the rules.

Board Game Geek doesn't have an "official" website either for the game, nor could I find one.

Answer (score 1):

We just got the game a few weeks ago as well. I found the rules here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6u03sg6m6dvtesn/rules.pdf?dl=1